# can't connect to a server through specific port

Tags: port, host

From my server I'm trying to connect to another server

I'm trying using the command via SSH

```
telnet 64.31.62.219 60099
```

it is connecting without problem on my local machine and from a server I already have also.

but when I try it on the server it can not connect with a timeout problem

I also tried to connect via port 80 and it connected without problem so the problem is that the server don't connect via the port 60099 although the destination already allowing the connection on that port

used the command

```
-iptables -L -n
```

gave results here http://justpaste.it/1cj4

any help ?

Comment: Can the server ping that IP?

Comment: Check log files and SELINUX status.

Comment: EH ?  You are trying to TELNET to a SSH service ??? That won't work. You will have to use a SSH client.